# libgdx - Trying to load ttf font using asset manager

Tags: android, libgdx, fonts, ttf

I tried to load a ttf font using an `AssetManager` like this:

```
FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter freeTypeFontLoaderParameter = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
freeTypeFontLoaderParameter.fontFileName = "fonts/zrnic.tff";

FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter freeTypeFontParameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
freeTypeFontParameter.minFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;
freeTypeFontParameter.magFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;
freeTypeFontParameter.flip = false;
freeTypeFontParameter.size = 62;

freeTypeFontLoaderParameter.fontParameters = freeTypeFontParameter;

game.assetManager.load("myFont62.ttf", BitmapFont.class, freeTypeFontLoaderParameter);
```

But I get

> Couldn't load dependencies of asset: myFont62.ttf

Comment: Put your zrnic.ttf in Assets folder (without any subfolders). Rename Assets folder to Assets2 and rename back to Assets (you have to close the IDE (And Studio/Eclipse/Intellij) before renaming). Change your fonts/zrnic.ttf to just "zrnic.ttf" and check if this works. If yes - post an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I updated the LibGDX wiki to specifically address this issue. The old example code used there was just too confusing for anyone to take a quick glance at and figure out what they were doing. Take a look when you get a chance.

Anyway, you're loading `myFont62.ttf` which is a string identifier of the resource `fonts/zrnic.ttf`. Instead of using a different name, you might try making the string identifier the same as the font resource. This makes it so that you aren't using two names for the same thing, and so that your string identifiers match your filenames.

Your problem is coming from a filesystem issue. It looks like your `assets/` folder is not recognizing the location `fonts/zrnic.ttf`. In your filesystem, you should have your font accessible as `yourgamefolder/android/assets/fonts/zrnic.ttf`

If it's anywhere else, you're going to get that error. As far as closing and re-opening the IDE, I've never ran into that problem, before. Just put your `fonts/` folder inside your `assets/` folder, and it should work just fine.